# Where can I download and how do I set up a 5-man tablebase in Arena GUI?

Tags: tablebases, arena

So, I want to download a 5-man tablebase (I have no disk space for a 6-man one) and set it up so that it works with Stockfish in Arena GUI. Where can I download the tablebase, and how do I install it in Arena GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://sites.google.com/site/gaviotachessengine/Home/endgame-tablebases-1
This tablebase was installed with arena 3.5.1

http://contentdb.emule-project.net/view.php?pid=1629 has Nalimov 5-man tablebases separated into the various 4-man configurations.

http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/tablebases-online/ has online databases, but you must install eMule to download.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cruxis.com/chess/manual/end_game_table_base_support.htm

This is from the developers of Houdini's site.